Vitest Async Mock Failing and Returning Undefined
I'm trying to write a unit test for an onMounted lifecycle hook for my Vue 3 component.  I'm mocking the resolved value for an async call but it keeps returning undefined.  As a result my last expect fails as it should receive 3 but receives 0.  How do I mock getDisclosuresListAsync to return a boolean:
This is the lifecycle hook:
  onMounted(async () => {
    applicationStore.updateShowSpinner(true);
    if (await disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync()) {
      disclosures.value = disclosureStore.disclosures;
      if (
        disclosures.value.length > 0 &&
        disclosures.value.length === selectedDisclosures.value.length
      ) {
        emit('form-status-updated', true, null);
      }
      applicationStore.updateShowSpinner(false);
      goTo(0, { duration: 200, easing: 'linear' });
    }
  });

This is the unit test:
  it('should get disclosures from the disclosureStore and populates the component disclosures on the onMounted lifecycle', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const appStore = mockedStore(useApplicationStore);
    appStore.updateShowSpinner.mockImplementation(() => {});

    const disclosureStore = mockedStore(useDisclosureStore);
    disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync.mockResolvedValue(true);
    wrapper.unmount();

    // Act
    wrapper = mount(BeginDisclosures, {
      global: {
        plugins: [
          createTestingPinia({
            initialState: {
              appStore: {
                //...removed for clarity
              },
              disclosureStore: {
                disclosures: [
                  <IDisclosure>{
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Disclosure 1',
                    displayName: 'Disclosure 1',
                    url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-1',
                  },
                  <IDisclosure>{
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Disclosure 2',
                    displayName: 'Disclosure 2',
                    url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-2',
                  },
                  <IDisclosure>{
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Disclosure 3',
                    displayName: 'Disclosure 3',
                    url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-3',
                  },
                ],
                selectedDisclosures: [],
                selectedDisclosuresReset: false
              }
            },
            createSpy: vi.fn
          }),
          vuetify
        ]
      }
    });
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    const disclosures = wrapper.vm.disclosures;

    // Assert
    expect(disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(disclosures.length).equals(3)
  });


I found a solution but it required me to restructure the component such that the logic in the lifecycle hook was encapsulated and extracted into a method and then tested the method directly.

Feel free to post this as an answer and accept it when you can.

I found a solution to my problem and wanted to post it here for anyone having a similar issue.  Basically, I restructured the component by moving the logic out of the lifecycle hook and testing the new method directly.
Here is the new method:
  const onMountedHandlerAsync = async () => {
    applicationStore.updateShowSpinner(true);
    if (await disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync()) {
      disclosures.value = disclosureStore.disclosures;
      if (
        disclosures.value.length > 0 &&
        disclosures.value.length === selectedDisclosures.value.length
      ) {
        emit('form-status-updated', true, null);
      }
      applicationStore.updateShowSpinner(false);
      goTo(0, { duration: 200, easing: 'linear' });
    }
  };

Here is the restructured lifecycle hook:
  onMounted(async () => {
    await onMountedHandlerAsync();
  });

Here is the unit test:
  it('should get disclosures from the disclosureStore and populates the component disclosures on the onMounted lifecycle', async () => {
    // Arrange
    const appStore = mockedStore(useApplicationStore);
    appStore.updateShowSpinner.mockImplementation(() => {});
    const disclosureStore = mockedStore(useDisclosureStore);
    disclosureStore.updateSelectedDisclosures.mockImplementation((selected: IDisclosure[]) => {
      const store = useDisclosureStore();
      store.$state.selectedDisclosures = selected;
    });
    disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync.mockResolvedValue(true)
    disclosureStore.disclosures = [
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Disclosure 1',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 1',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-1',
      },
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Disclosure 2',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 2',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-2',
      },
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Disclosure 3',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 3',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-3',
      },
    ];
    wrapper.vm.selectedDisclosures = [
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Disclosure 1',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 1',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-1',
      },
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Disclosure 2',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 2',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-2',
      },
      <IDisclosure>{
        id: 3,
        name: 'Disclosure 3',
        displayName: 'Disclosure 3',
        url: 'http://localhost/api/disclosures/disclosure-3',
      },
    ];

    // Act
    await wrapper.vm.onMountedHandlerAsync();
    await flushPromises();

    const disclosures = wrapper.vm.disclosures;

    // Assert
    expect(disclosureStore.getDisclosuresListAsync).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(disclosures.length).equals(3)
  });

